# how to find tfslim output node names

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

After training some model with tensorflow and slim, I am trying to freeze the model and weights. But it's quite hard for me to find out the output nodes name, which is necessary for `freeze_graph.freeze_graph()`.

my output layers looks like:

```
 conv4_1 = slim.conv2d(net,num_outputs=2,kernel_size=[1,1],stride=1,scope='conv4_1',activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax)
    #conv4_1 = slim.conv2d(net,num_outputs=1,kernel_size=[1,1],stride=1,scope='conv4_1',activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid)

    print conv4_1.get_shape()
    #batch*H*W*4
    bbox_pred = slim.conv2d(net,num_outputs=4,kernel_size=[1,1],stride=1,scope='conv4_2',activation_fn=None)
```

conv4_1 is the softmaxed class like, face or not.
bbox_pred is the bounding box regression.

when I save the graph with, `tf.train.write_graph(self.sess.graph_def, output_path, 'model.pb')` and open the model.pb as text, I found that the graph looks like:

```
node {
name: "conv4_1/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/shape"
...
node {
name: "conv4_1/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer"
...
node {
name: "conv4_1/Conv2D"
op: "Conv2D"
input: "conv3/add"
input: "conv4_1/weights/read"
...
node {
name: "conv4_1/Softmax"
op: "Softmax"
input: "conv4_1/Reshape"
...
node {
  name: "Squeeze"
  op: "Squeeze"
  input: "conv4_1/Reshape_1"
  attr {
    key: "T"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "squeeze_dims"
    value {
      list {
        i: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so, here comes the problem, which is the output node names?

tensorflow only ways of writing layers could set "names" like:

```
             .conv(3, 3, 32, 1, 1, padding='VALID', relu=False, name='conv3')
         .prelu(name='PReLU3')
         .conv(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, relu=False, name='conv4-1')
         .softmax(3,name='prob1'))

    (self.feed('PReLU3') #pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
         .conv(1, 1, 4, 1, 1, relu=False, name='conv4-2'))
```

But I can't find setting output names method in tensorflow slim.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Output Node names for the 3 of the inception models are given below:

inception v3 : InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1 
inception v4 : InceptionV4/Logits/Predictions 
inception resnet v2 : InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions

Comment: How did you find the output node names for the above 3 models? I'm looking for the input and output node names of TF Slim Resnet_v1_50 and Resnet_v2_50 but cannot find them.